# How do i deploy two different web apps to single Azure App Service with different custom domains?

Tags: azure, deployment, ssl-certificate, azure-app-service-plans, custom-domain

I have two different web apps I would like to deploy to my Azure App Service I have purchased separate domains for each app. Can I deploy into the available deployment slots in the app service and connect their respective domains? Reason: I have a wildcard SSL I want to bind to this App Service

Answer (score 0):

If your apps share the same subscription then you should be able to choose the same app service certifcicate for both of them within the portal.

If they are in different subscriptions then the solution would be to download the certificate as a PFX and then upload this to your second site. You can do this with the following powershell:

> vaultName = 'keyvault-where-cert-is-stored' $secretName =
>   'name-of-the-cert-certificate' $cert = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret
>   -VaultName $vaultName -Name $secretName $pfxBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($cert.SecretValueText)
>   [io.file]::WriteAllBytes("c:\temp\$secretName.pfx", $pfxBytes)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/08f1248f-0009-4a44-a787-226b183f023c/use-same-wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-two-different-web-apps-in-different-regions?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create two different app services. Each of your web app will go to each of the app service. Please note that several app services **can share one single app service plan**, so creating 2 apps doesn't bill you twice as much. Follow the general rule: one app for one codebase.
2. If you have a wild card SSL, you can apply the same SSL certificate to the 2 apps that we created in step one. For help with adding SSL certificates to azure app service, take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate)